# Guice Typeliteral for kotlin collection (e.g. kotlin.collections.Iterable) searches for java.lang.Iterable

Tags: java, kotlin, dependency-injection, guice

#### Problem

In kotlin, with the following module configuration for guice

```kotlin
fun configureFoo(binder: Binder) {
  binder.bind(object: TypeLiteral<Foo<Iterable<Any>>>() {}).to(MyFoo::class.java)
}
```

And the example classes

```kotlin
interface Foo<T> {
  // ...
}

class MyFoo : Foo<Iterable<Any>> {
  // ...
}
```

```kotlin
class User @Inject constructor(foo: Foo<Iterable<Any>>) {
  // ...
}
```

I get the guice configuration error:

```
No implementation for Foo<java.lang.Iterable<Any>> was bound. ...
```

#### What I've tried

I can fix this by changing `Iterable` to `java.lang.Iterable` everywhere... but thats a bad workaround loosing all the benefits of `kotlin.collections.Iterable`.

#### Question

Does anyone know this problem and has a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

#### Simple workaround until a better solution arrives

Right now I'm using a workaround as follows, in case anyone stumbles upon that problem:

I define specialized `MultiFoo<Any>`s and use them instead of `Foo<Iterable<Any>>` whenever I want to use an iterable type-parameter for Foo:

```kotlin
fun configureFoo(binder: Binder) {
  // bind an iterable Any for Foo
  binder.bind(object: TypeLiteral<MultiFoo<Any>>() {}).to(MyFoo::class.java)

  // bind a single Any For Foo
  binder.bind(object: TypeLiteral<Foo<Any>>() {}).to(MySingleFoo::class.java)
}
```

```kotlin
interface Foo<T> {
  // ...
}
interface MultiFoo<T>: Foo<Iterable<T>> {
  // ...
}

class MyFoo : MultiFoo<Any> {
  // ...
}

class MySingleFoo : Foo<Any> {
  // ...
}
```

```kotlin
class User @Inject constructor(foo: MultiFoo<Any>, bar: Foo<Any>) {
  // ...
}
```

Although it is not very beautiful to create and use extra classes for injection-binding and constructor-parameters, but at least the injected-classes adhere to the desired interface-contracts... I can use `MultiFoo<Any>` as a `Foo<Iterable<Any>>`